# Downloading and extracting a .tar to a specific directory

Tags: bash, curl

I want to download a tar of a git repo and extract its contents to another folder.

The following line (broken up for clarity) works:

```
curl -L -0 nt-dotfiles.tar.gz https://api.github.com/repos/nicktomlin/laptop/tarball \
 | tar --strip-components=1 -zx -C ~/Documents/dotfiles
```

but gives gives this error:

`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nt-dotfiles.tar.gz; nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

I'm fine with leaving things as-is (because it still works) but I'm curious about the error, and would feel better if it went away.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, the message is saying that it is expecting a host (like a web URL) but instead getting a file (which can't resolve to an IP).

Comment: your syntax is wrong. take a look at the manual: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your syntax should be: `curl -L -o nt-dotfiles.tar.gz https://api. ...`  You are using a zero instead of lower case 'Oh'.  Zero forces curl to use http1.0.  'o' provides an output  filename.

From the man page:

```
-0, --http1.0
          (HTTP)  Forces curl to issue its requests using HTTP 1.0 instead
          of using its internally preferred: HTTP 1.1. 


-o, --output <file>
          Write output to <file> instead of stdout. If you are using {} or
          [] to fetch multiple documents, you can use '#'  followed  by  a
          number  in  the <file> specifier. That variable will be replaced
          with the current string for the URL being fetched. Like in:

            curl http://{one,two}.site.com -o "file_#1.txt"
```

Comment: also, URL syntax is protocol dependent, refer to this RFC for clarification: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: +1 for your totally clear edit explaining arguments.

Comment: not to comment snipe, but after accepting this I've noticed that using ``-o`` does not actually extract the archive. If I use ``-0`` (which I know is wrong) the archive gets extracted to the folder I specify with ``tar -C``. I get the ``could not resolve host:`` error, but it works. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickTomlin OK, try not using the `-o` option at all.  I originally suggested it because I thought that's what you were trying to do with the `-0`.  I think that not having the `-o filename` option will allow you to pipe the `curl`ed file to the tar command.  As I said in the answer, the `-0` option is definitely not what you want, so maybe the original answer should have been to just remove it.  PS:  I'd say a comment snipe is justifiable in the circumstances :-)

Answer (score 14):

You may try:

```
$ curl -s http://example.com/file.tgz | tar xvf - -C dest/
```

Comment: `dest/` would need to exists first